# Spring Data - Projection and @Query nested property

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Assume I have those DTO:

```
public interface ForumDTO extends ForumBaseDTO{
    Integer getId();
    ThreadDTO getLastThread();
}
public interface ThreadDTO {
    Integer getId();
    Integer getCommentCount()
}
```

In my Repository I have this query using those DTO as projection:

```
   @Query("select forum.id as id, " +
   "forum.name as name, " +
   "lastThread.id as lastThread_id " +
   "from Forum forum " +
   "inner join forum.lastThread as lastThread " +
   "where forum.parent.id = ?:"
   )
   Iterable<ForumDTO> findAllByParentId(Integer id);
```

I can access id,name in ForumDTO using this repo just fine, but with lastThread it just return null. I have tried `as lastThread.Id`,`as lastThread_id`, `as lastThreadId` but none of them work.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.

You need to access it from forum to follow out the foreign key:

```
@Query("select forum.id as id, " +
   "forum.name as name, " +
   "**forum.lastThread.id** as lastThread_id " +
   "from Forum forum " +
   "inner join forum.lastThread as lastThread " +
   "where forum.parent.id = ?:"
   )
   Iterable<ForumDTO> findAllByParentId(Integer id);
```

That said, you're killing yourself with extra work.
The same Query can be written as:

```
@Query("select forum from Forum where forum.parent.id = :forumId")
Iterable<ForumDTO> findAllByParentId(@Param("forumId")Integer id);
```

You just need to make sure that the foreign key to `Parent` is present on the entity.

Also notice the `@Param` annotation. It makes your parameters easier to track, and also does some basic type checking against the db. It's very useful to prevent SQL injection attacks, and `UncheckedTypeException`s.

Comment: But when ThreadDTO has a field like getCommentCount that is computated by using count(comments.id) your way doesn't work. Initially, I use the field name so I can use count() function

Comment: That's a different issue. Aggregates are a little tricky in JPA, but the reason your'e getting the issue you are with this one is that you aren't properly following the foreign key path.